# TRPC, tanstack/react-query, Next.js No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I'm having difficulties with TRPC (10.9.0) & tanstack/react-query (4.10.0) Next.js app. As other answers here suggested I wrapped my _app.tsx in <QueryClientProvider> but still get this error.

```
// _app.tsx
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { trpc, client } from "../src/services";
import { QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={client}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

export default trpc.withTRPC(App);
```

```
// src/services/index.tsx
import { AppRouter } from "server";
import { createTRPCNext } from "@trpc/next";
import { httpBatchLink } from "@trpc/client";
import { QueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export const client = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});


export const trpc = createTRPCNext<AppRouter>({
  config() {
    return {
      links: [
        httpBatchLink({
          url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL as string,
        }),
      ],
    };
  },
  ssr: false,
});
```

I'm using trpc query inside /pages/index.tsx

I was trying to add QueryClientProvider just as error message stated but no results

Answer (score 2):

tRPC provides a [built-in way to pass options](https://trpc.io/docs/client/nextjs/setup#config-callback) to the `QueryClient` it automatically constructs when using the `createTRPCNext` method via the `queryClientConfig` option:

```js
export const trpc = createTRPCNext<AppRouter>({
  config() {
    return {
      queryClientConfig: {
        defaultOptions: {
          queries: { staleTime: 5000, refetchOnWindowFocus: false },
        },
      },
      links: [
        httpBatchLink({
          url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL as string,
        }),
      ],
    };
  },
  ssr: false,
});
```

Alternatively, if you do want to construct the `QueryClient` yourself, you can pass the query client in via the `queryClient` option:

```js
const client = new QueryClient({
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    },
  },
});


export const trpc = createTRPCNext<AppRouter>({
  config() {
    return {
      queryClient: client,
      links: [
        httpBatchLink({
          url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL as string,
        }),
      ],
    };
  },
  ssr: false,
});
```

With these options set, you don't need to use the `QueryClientProvider` in your `_app.tsx` and just revert to only `trpc.withTRPC`. I.e.

```js
// _app.tsx
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { trpc } from "../src/services";

const App = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  return (
     <Component {...pageProps} />
  );
};

export default trpc.withTRPC(App);
```